# powershell: if loop, while the first position of arraylist in in process

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have an arraylist, in which I am going to save some values. I am doing a foreach loop and if a value is going to be saved at the first position of the ArrayList, I want to output a "First position" line and otherwise, nothing should be done.
**The if block that I wrote below, doesn't work.**

```
<# Don't consider this code from here

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$alist = @()
$al ="keeranpc01,www.google.ch,192.168.0.25"

$al = $al.Split(",")
foreach($h in $al){
    # Abstand vor dem Hostnamen löschen
    if($h.contains(' ')) {
        $h = $h -replace '\s', ''
    }
    $alist.Add($h)
}
to here
#>


#### Start here
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$rear = @()

foreach($ha in $alist) {
    $PingConnetion = Test-Connection $ha -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $pcre = $ha
    $pire =  if($PingConnetion.ResponseTime -ne $null) {Write-output 'Erreichbar'}else{Write-Output 'Nicht Erreichbar'}
    $zure = $PingConnetion.ResponseTime 
    $zeit = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss

    if($alist[$_] -eq $alist[0]) {Write-Host 'First position'}
    [void]$rear.Add([PSCustomObject]@{Zeit = $zeit; Host = $pcre; IPv4 = $PingConnetion.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString; Ping = $pire; Zugriffszeit = $zure; })
}
```

how should I write the if statement so that it is possible? I expect if-statement to work, Only when the first position of ArrayList is in process

thx

Comment: `if($rear.Count -eq 0){Write-Host...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are tying to do does work except you are tying to compare element zero of your alist to a ordinal position of your alist which is invalid. You would need to compare the following:

```
if($ha -eq $alist[0]) {Write-Host 'First position'}
```

Below is a worked example that might be clearer.

```
$input = 1..10    
foreach($x in $input){
    if($input[0] -eq $x){
        write-host "First Position"
    }
    $x
}
```

Comment: thx for the quick reply. If I put the foreach loop into a while loop, everytime when the foreach loop stars again, I see the "First Position" massage. How can I avoid that repeating, when the forecah loop is into a while loop, which just executes the foreach loop , until cancelled.

Comment: if you have nested loops you need to test both loops. set a variable to indicate if this is the first time through the outer loop and test that on the inner loop  to see if its is the first time through both loops. You will need to set the first time through outer loop variable to false at the end of the first iteration of the while loop.